# Ошибка Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую код, который успешно работает на 3 сайтах (отправка заявки из формы на e-mail и вывод окна благодарности).

При попытке запустить его на новом сайте выскакивает ошибка в консоли Хрома (и в других браузерах): http://prntscr.com/8n0rs4 (скриншот).

Код формы и JS:

```
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="text" align="center">
            <form id="mailer_form" action="mailer.php" method="post" class="form1"> 
                        <h3>Оставьте заявку и<br>получите расчет стоимости</h3>
                        <input type="text" name="name" class="inputbox" placeholder="Ваше имя:" required>
                        <input type="text" name="phone" class="inputbox" placeholder="Ваш телефон:" required>

                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="button" value="Заказать цветы">
                         <a href="#close" title="Закрыть"></a>
            </form>
    </div>

</div>
```

```html
 <script>
//callback handler for form submit
$("#mailer_form").submit(function(e) {
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            data_result = JSON.parse(data);
   if(typeof data_result === 'undefined') {
    // alert('Problem with returned JSON');
   }else{
    if(parseInt(data_result.success) === 1 && parseInt(data_result.error) === 0) {
     var html_result="<h3>Спасибо за вашу заявку!<br><br>Мы свяжемся с Вами<br>в ближайшее время!</h3><img src='img/up.png' style='margin-top: 35px;'>"
     $('div#modal div.text').html(html_result);
     //alert("OK");
    }else if(parseInt(data_result.success) === 0 && parseInt(data_result.error) === 1) {
     // alert(data_result.msg);
    }
   }
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
           // alert("Error!");
     console.log(data);
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    // e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
</script>
```

Повторюсь, что этот код работает на других сайтах отлично. Копировал 1 в 1, подключены те же скрипты.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: P.S. Форма срабатывает и заявка на почту уходит. Но не изменяется информация в теге <h1></h1> - по идее должна замениться надпись.

Comment: Ну а json как выглядит?

Comment: Не совсем понял вопроса :) Я новичок в JS)

Comment: Сам столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решил ее просматривая аналогичный код других специалистов. Повнимательнее к знакам препинания. У меня в созданном объекте стояла ; хотя правильно просто , Из-за этого весь сыр бор

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас не срабатывает второе условие в функции success, а именно:

```
if(parseInt(data_result.success) === 1 && parseInt(data_result.error) === 0) {

    var html_result="<h3>Спасибо за вашу заявку!<br><br>Мы свяжемся с Вами<br>в ближайшее время!</h3><img src='img/up.png' style='margin-top: 35px;'>"

    $('div#modal div.text').html(html_result);

    //alert("OK");

}
```

Если в JSON ответе условия `parseInt(data_result.success) === 1` **и** `parseInt(data_result.error) === 0` **точно** срабатывают, то поставьте "**;**" после строки

```
var html_result="<h3>Спасибо за вашу заявку!<br><br>Мы свяжемся с Вами<br>в ближайшее время!</h3><img src='img/up.png' style='margin-top: 35px;'>"
```

Должно сработать.

Comment: Специально проверил этот момент на других сайта (с этим же кодом) - там нет ";" и всё работает.

Поставил ";" у себя сейчас, всё равно та же ошибка :(

Comment: Тогда в FireBag в Mozilla FF скопируйте ответный код из консоли и скиньте посмотреть.

Comment: 1. Этот сайт использует сертификат SHA-1; рекомендуется использовать сертификаты с алгоритмами подписи, использующими более сильные хеш-функции, чем SHA-1.

2. SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 2 column 1 of the JSON data

P.S. При клике на вторую ошибку, указывает ошибку здесь:
data_result = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Тогда попробуйте строку `data_result = JSON.parse(data);` заменить на `data_result = data;`

Но вы все же не то скопировали. Нужен JSON ответ, а не ошибки.

Comment: При data_result = data; ошибки нет никакой, но форма не изменяет значение в теге <h1>

Насчет "Нужен JSON ответ, а не ошибки." - дико извиняюсь за нубство, но подскажите, пожалуйста, как это посмотреть?

Comment: В консоли в FireBug при отправке формы должно появиться запрос(в вашем случает post), на скрипт, который в свою очередь возвращает данные в формате JSON. Когда запрос закончится, кликаете на эту ссылку и там найдете вкладку "Ответ".

Comment: Оно?
http://prntscr.com/8n9xld

Comment: Да. Ошибка на стороне сервера. Запрос обрабатывается, но ответ не приходит. Ищите её там.

Comment: Т.е. проблема может быть в хостинге?

Comment: Нет, скрипт на серверном языке написан неправильно. В вашем случае, наверно, это PHP.

Comment: Вы гений. Огромное спасибо.

Код JS я-то скопировал (да, мне помогали с его написанием), а вот PHP-код (который отправлял заявку) отличался от того, что использовался на других сайтах. Подправил и всё стало отлично.

Огромное Вам спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

просто добавь перед `data_result = JSON.parse(data);` вот это

```
console.log('RESPONDE=>'+data);
```

потом перезагрузи страницу, нажми правой кнопкой и выбери инструменты разработчика
выполни действие и увидишь полученный результат
Скорее всего у тебя получен неправильный JSON или его вообще нет.

Comment: Не после, а перед. Если JSON.parse упадёт, то выводить будет уже некому.

Comment: да, совершенно верно